# Adjust the height of a DIV to how much content there is on a page

Tags: css

I want to dim the content on my website on click on a link in the menu. The logotype and the menu shall not be dimmed. [This example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/8MGzB/) shows exactly what I mean. The `dim-page` DIV shall adjust its height according to how much content there is on the specific page.

For example, on the jsFiddle page I have 5 rows of text. When I click on the link in the content, `dim-page` will be visible and it dims only the half if the content because it has a fixed height. How can I make this height dynamic according to how much content there is on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set dim height after get height of content div

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link').click(function() {
        var contentHeight = $(".content").outerHeight();
        $('.dim-page').show().height(contentHeight);
    });
});
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Many thanks :D I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.